# Run twice with Docker and docker-compose

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a Spring Boot application that I am trying to set up reloading for during development. I am using Docker compose with a volume mount to map the host directory into the application container.

When I enable reloading so that code changes are automatically reflected, it causes the application to run twice.

Is this expected behavior? Am I configuring something incorrectly that is causing it to double up like this during hot reloading?

Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17-slim AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY pom.xml .

RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B

COPY src ./src

RUN mvn package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim AS runtime

COPY --from=build /app/target/book-course-1.0.0.jar .

CMD ["java", "-jar", "book-course-1.0.0.jar"]

WORKDIR /app
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  version: "3.7"
  services:
    app:
    build: .
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
       - $SPRING_PORT:$SPRING_PORT
    depends_on:
       - mysqldb
    volumes:
       - .:/app
    restart: on-failure
    command: sh -c "./mvnw spring-boot:run"
    mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.22
```

Answer (score 1):

Am not quite sure, But `dockerfile` is a build stage file. Meaning, It will only be used when you build the image. Once you have a built image, No changes can be effected the already-built image.

I think you are looking for devtools setup, but again, If you are using the CMD to run an already existing JAR, Devtools wont have any effect, As the image was built. and the CMD already running the old JAR.

I think ( not 100% sure ) You need to run the application with Gradle/Maven command like, This will have devtools to be triggered once a file is changed.

your Volume should look like this:

```
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/target
```

Add devtools to your maven/gradle config, And by default, DevTools doesn't detect changes to files that are outside of the classpath, which includes files that are in the `/app` directory that we mounted as a volume. To fix this, you can add the following configuration to your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=/app
```

Comment: I test it but it did not work

Comment: an error log ? or just no error message ?

Comment: Without error message, It run correctly but project is not restarting to pick up the changes.

Comment: How are you running spring boot ?

Comment: Yes, Tomcat runned on port 8081.

Comment: how ? usin `CMD ["java", "-jar", "book-course-1.0.0.jar"]`

Comment: Yes, I also add voulmes and that command in application.properties.

Comment: and still, running with an already created Jar file? try to replace the command with `CMD ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]` but make sure you have `devtools` in the `pom.xml` file

Comment: It have error: `failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "mvn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Comment: before the cmd command , try adding `ENV PATH="/usr/share/maven/bin:${PATH}"` to dockerfile and rebuild

Comment: I don't know this error. `Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "mvn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Comment: try to locate where the MAVEN is and call it foe execution, running `CMD ["java", "-jar", "book-course-1.0.0.jar"]` will not work, as you are successfully running this Jar, and it will not have devtools effect. To use devtools you will need to run with either maven or gradle. I can provide a docker file to make it work, But it will be out of your question scope.

Comment: Does that mean we don't have hot reload despite Docker?

Comment: No there is, if you mounted the files correctly, and devtools is added correctly, inside the container should behave in the exact same way as outside, which mean there is a way.

Comment: I find a way but my project run twice. Can you guide me?https://gist.github.com/alidehkhodaei/7620b1d9afbef1064615869a15500b15

Comment: Can you update the question with the log required? or even better, Ask a new question with the `compose` file used, `dockerfile` and containers list to get a better view what application running twice means.

Comment: I changed my question.

Comment: how are you running with these files ?

Comment: Yes, I run with these files.

Comment: how ? what is the command, `docker-compose up --build -d` ?

Comment: `docker-compose up --build`